# Getting names of past days (ex: 7 days ago, 8 days ago ...)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find names of past days. I'm using this script to get names of past 7 days successfully, however, it doesn't work if I increase the past days, for example 7 days ago, 8 days ago or more.

```
var dayOfWeek = new Array();  

dayOfWeek[0] = "Sun";  
dayOfWeek[1] = "Mon";  
dayOfWeek[2] = "Tue";  
dayOfWeek[3] = "Wed";  
dayOfWeek[4] = "Thu";  
dayOfWeek[5] = "Fri";  
dayOfWeek[6] = "Sat";  

var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate());
var myDate1 = new Date();
myDate1.setDate(myDate1.getDate() - 1);
var myDate2 = new Date();
myDate2.setDate(myDate2.getDate() - 2);
var myDate3 = new Date();
myDate3.setDate(myDate3.getDate() - 3);
var myDate4 = new Date();
myDate4.setDate(myDate4.getDate() - 4);
var myDate5 = new Date();
myDate5.setDate(myDate5.getDate() - 5);
var myDate6 = new Date();
myDate6.setDate(myDate6.getDate() - 6);

var on1 = dayOfWeek[myDate.getDay()];
var on2 = dayOfWeek[myDate1.getDay()];
var on3 = dayOfWeek[myDate2.getDay()];
var on4 = dayOfWeek[myDate3.getDay()];
var on5 = dayOfWeek[myDate4.getDay()];
var on6 = dayOfWeek[myDate5.getDay()];

document.write(on5);
```

What is the correct way to do that ?

Comment: you may consider moment js http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to do something like (assuming today is Wednesday):

- 2 days ago was Monday
- 5 days ago was Friday
- 8 days ago was Tuesday

If this is correct, then this should do it:

```
function getDayOfWeekAgo(daysAgo) {
    var today = new Date().getDay(),
        days = ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"];
    today = (today+daysAgo*6)%7; // adding 6 per day is the same as subtracting one
                              // due to the modulo, just without the complications
                              // that negative numbers would bring
    return days[today];
}
```

Or, more efficiently:

```
window.getDayOfWeekAgo = (function() {
    var today = new Date().getDay(),
        days = ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"];
    return function(daysAgo) {return days[(today+daysAgo*6)%7];}
})();
```

Comment: I tried getDayOfWeekAgo(2) and get "undefined". How should I use it ?

Comment: My mistake, I used the same variable name twice. Will edit real quick.

Comment: Ok, it works now. And by the way, which timezone is it using ? browser time ? I used getDayOfWeekAgo(1) and it gives me today's time (in my timezone gmt +3)

Comment: It uses the browser's time. If you want it in UTC, you can use `getUTCDay` instead of `getDay`.